# Laravel-Mail: How to pass ->attachData to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to use an inline attachment in laravel mail but seems unfortunate. I also tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829906/sending-base64-images-using-laravel) but doesn't work by embeding of raw data. I have a base 64 image/png here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/eu844vcL/) of it.

Now I'm trying to use attachData but how can I pass the `->attachData` to my `mailtransaction.blade`. I supposedly get the attachData from my controller but what variable should I call?

Controller.php

```
Mail::send(['html'=>'mailtransaction'], $data_content, function($msg) use ($to, $issueType, $base64){
        $msg->to($to); // change this upon finishing
        $msg->attachData($base64, 'test.png', ['mime'=>'image/png']);
        $msg->subject($issueType);
      });
```

mailtransaction.blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="width:100%;">
    <div style="border:0px solid #000; width:1000px !important;">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="{{$message->embed('storage/app/public/images/logo.png')}}" height="50px" width="50px">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="font-size:24px; margin-bottom: -10px;">Fraud Detection Tool</div>
            <div>Suspicious Transaction details</div>
        </div>
        <hr style="border:0px; border-bottom:1px solid #000; width:1000px;">
        <div class="container">
            {{$msg}}
            //I supposedly get the attachData from my controller but what variable should I call?
        </div>
        <hr style="width:1000px;">
        <div class="container_mail" style="width:600px !important;">
            <img src="{{}}" height="auto" style="max-width: 1000px">
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could it be because $request is not passed in `use`?

Comment: @clod986 I edit my question yea it should be in use, but my question is how could I call that ->attachData to  pass in my mail vue

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data to your view as the `second` argument of `send()` method and it needs to be an `array` of data. Change your controller to -

```
Mail::send('mailtransaction', ['data_content'=>$data_content,'base64'=>$base64], function($msg) use ($to, $issueType){
    $msg->to($to); // change this upon finishing
    $msg->attachData($request->getBase64, 'test.png', ['mime'=>'image/png']);
    $msg->subject($issueType);
  });
```

And in your view, you can access `data_content` and `base64` as-

```
{{$data_content}}
{{$base64}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `attachData` method adds an email attachment and doesn't work for inline images. You need to add your image data to your $data_content variable and refer to it from there:

```
$data_content['attachedImage'] = ...; // Get the regular data of the image, not the base64 version
```

and then in your template use the `embedData` method:

```
<img src="{{ $message->embedData($attachedImage, 'test.png') }}" align="right" width="150px" height="100px"/>
```

If you need to leave the data as base64 then just pass the data into `$data_content` as base64 and use it this way:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $attachedImage }}" align="right" width="100px" height="100px"/>
```

Comment: But my image is from my script file and converted into base64 its not a typical image I just captured the div content using html2canvas then pass it to my server

Comment: But you are still attempting to display it in the email as a PNG file, correct?

Comment: Yea I it should be displaying in email as png image

Comment: If so then you will want to use the embedData command. If you need to leave it as base64 you can use the edit I made to the post to display inline base64 in your email.